# How to generate multiple maps where one highlighted attribute changes?

Tags: qgis, qgis-2

I have a layer that contains counties within the state of Washington.

I need to build one map (jpg) for each county.  For that specific map all counties will show as light grey, but the specific county will be green, and the file name will be the county name.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What you want is creating the **Atlas**.

1. In print composer, go to *Atas generation tab* and check *Generate atlas*.
2. As *covarage layer* set your counties layer, and as output set your name of counties attribute (somtheing like `"counties_names"`).
3. Go to layer properties and set rule-based symbology, create empty rule with grey color and in this rule nest a rule like `$id  =  @atlas_featureid` with green color (see picture below).

[image]

4. Go back to print composer and start preview of atlas (in atlas panel or menu *Atlas --> Preview Atlas*. Now you can browse atlas features by *Next feature* and *Previous feture* and so on.
5. If you wnat add other items like text fields, scalebar etc. (You can also control text fields by expression, so you can get for each atlas feature uniqe text fields values, for example counties names.)
6. Export via atlas panel or menu *Atlas --> Export Atlas as Images...*

Possible output (one of exported images):

[image]

Comment: Good answer, you just forgot to explain how to use the county name in the outptu file.

Comment: Wow, so much easier that I expect, and yet another part of QGIS I never new about.  The graphics were a great help, btw.

Comment: @AlexandreNeto it is in step 2 ;)

Answer (score 0):

Further too Oto Kaláb.

To invert the selection you need to use the != on the grey color. see my example below.

[image]