# Marking Layer in Atlas without zooming

Tags: qgis, atlas

QGIS 2.18. (Las Palmas)

I would like to create a series of maps, where I rather than zooming to the coverage Layer, i would only highlight the filter i used (for example with a different color) but still want to be able to see the whole map. Is there a possibility to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you need to fix the extent of the whole map and highlight only the polygon without zooming. I will based my answer on another creative answer to this [question:How to generate multiple maps where one highlighted attribute changes?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/221788/how-to-generate-multiple-maps-where-one-highlighted-attribute-changes), but with some modifications that you need to fix the scale and extent of the map view inside the print composer.

1. Follow the steps answered by [Oto Kaláb](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/221791/63384) to highlight only one polygon at a time
2. After you are satisfied with scale, you need to fix the scale and extent of the map in the print composer by simply copy the value of the scale and paste it in the expression beside the scale. Also, copy each value under extent and paste it in the expression beside each one, as you can see below:

[image]

Example to fix scale value:

[image]

3. Go to `Atlas generation`, and select the coverage layer, and select the field that defines `Page name`
4. Then check `Controlled by Atlas`, and select `Fixed Scale`
5. Click on Preview Atlas, and you will get the following results:

[image]

[image]

[image]