# Show attributes of area of interest by using Atlas

Tags: qgis, print-composer, atlas

I use the "Atlas" tool of QGIS 2.18 to generate maps of different districts of my "city" layer. The information shown inside every district are the name, a value for power, and a pie chart. When I change between the single maps of the atlas, I would like to have only the information shown, which are interesting for the special district. The information of the residual district should be hidden.

I already found a way to select only the district of interest by using $id = $atlasfeature for stile and label, but I can't hide the  diagram...

Is there a way to do so?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For **lables** use *Rule-based labeling* (you already figure it out) similar way as in symbology ([How to generate multiple maps where one highlighted attribute changes?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/221788/how-to-generate-multiple-maps-where-one-highlighted-attribute-changes/221791#221791)) using `$id = @atlas_featureid` expression.

In case of **diagrams** it's bit a tricky because there isn't any direct rule-based option. But you can use this simple workaround based on defining size of diagrams:

In *Diagrams* tab, go to *Size* option and select *Scaled size* and as Attribute use case conditional like `CASE WHEN $id = @atlas_featureid THEN 20 END`, which define size only for atlas feature (other features will be left with no size). You also have to set *Maximum value* and *Size* (scale) values to get diagram of required size.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for support me on easter holiday^^ .... gues thats the egg I had to find :P... smart solution!