# Show diagrams of area of interest by using Atlas, QGIS

Tags: atlas, qgis-3

I use the Atlas of QGIS 3.2. I already figured out how to show only attributes inside current Atlas feature using `$id = @atlas_featureid`.

My problem is, as a coverage layer I am using layer with municipality borders, although my featured layer has borders of smaller administrative units. When I use the `$id = @atlas_featureid`, Atlas only shows one diagram per Map.

I partially found a solution to hide diagrams outside current map feature in this [thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/236854/show-attributes-of-area-of-interest-by-using-atlas?newreg=209d5a372382418db2ab6f1492f22fb7), but it doesn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to show all the features that fall within your atlas feature then you want an expression like:

```
contains(  @atlas_geometry , $geometry )
```

that will select all of the features who's geometry falls within the atlas feature's geometry.